# Voltage divisor on a oscillator output using Capacitors vs Resistors

Tags: oscillator, crystal

My question is pretty simple.
Why does this chip datasheet suggest to use a voltage divisor using capacitors? Does it make a difference to use capacitors instead of resistors?

Edit: Link to datasheet -  Page 800
https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/datasheets/i210-ethernet-controller-datasheet.pdf

[image]

Comment: always include links to datasheet in question

Comment: with a datasheet of some 900 pages it would be wise to also include the page number.

Comment: added link and page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

XTAL_IN on the destination device may have very little scope to deal with slight offsets of its natural DC operating level. So, if you were to use a resistor divider you may well have to add a third component, namely a capacitor between the divided down signal and XTAL_IN.

It's likely that the oscillator pins on the destination device uses a high value resistor between OUT and IN to naturally set the optimum DC bias point at IN. This is because internally it is likely to be a CMOS inverter made to operate linearly using typically a 1 Mohm feedback resistor.

The other issue is the XTAL_IN input capacitance. It's likely to be several pico-farad and if you used a resistor divider, the natural input capacitance would create a phase error and may even attenuate the resistor-divided signal so much that it just won't work.

Using a capacitor divider works on both issues mentioned above.

This is typical of what might be seen behind the pins XTAL_IN and OUT: -

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I made it work with a resistor divider but will update it for the capacitors